# Table field naming convention and SQL statements

Tags: sql

I have a practical question regarding naming table fields in a database. For example, I have two tables:

```
student (id int; name varchar(30))
teacher (id int, s_id int; name varchar(30))
```

There are both 'id' and "name" in two tables. In SQL statement, it will be ambiguous for the two if no table names are prefixed. Two options:

1. use Table name as prefix of a field in SQL 'where' clause
2. use prefixed field names in tables so that no prefix will be used in 'where' clause.

Which one is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For queries that aren't ad-hoc, you should *always* prefix every field with either the table name or table alias, even if the field name isn't ambiguous. This prevents the query from breaking later if someone adds a new column to one of the tables that introduces ambiguity.

So that would make "id" and "name" unambiguous. But I still recommend naming the primary key with something more specific than "id". In your example, I would use `student_id` and `teacher_id`. This helps prevent mistakes in joins. You will need more specific names anyway when you run into tables with more than one unique key, or multi-part keys.

It's worth thinking these things through, but in the end consistency may be the more important factor. I can deal with tables built around `id` instead of `student_id`, but I'm currently working with an inconsistent schema that uses all of the following: `id`, `sid`, `systemid` and specific names like `taskid`. That's the worst of both worlds.

Comment: Yes, always qualify **all** column references in a query. It prevents the query from breaking in the future when someone adds a column in a table (introducing ambiguous column reference errors). And, it makes it easier for a later reader to decipher the SQL... that unqualified reference the `foobar` column... is that a reference to a column in the `fee` table, the `fi` table or the `fo` table? (Don't you dare make me go hunt through the table definitions to find out which table that refers to.)  But my personal preference is to name the column `id` where it's the primary (or unique) key.

Answer (score 3):

Without a doubt, go with option 1.  This is valid sql in any type of database and considered the proper and most readable format.  It's good habit to prefix the table name to a column, and very necessary when doing a join.  The only exception to this I've most often seen is prefixing the id column with the table name, but I still wouldn't do that.
If you go with option 2, seasoned DBA's will probably point and laugh at you.
For further proof, see #2 here:  https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/better-sql-schema.html 
And here.  Rule 1b - http://www.isbe.net/ILDS/pdf/SQL_server_standards.pdf

As TT mentions, you'll make your life much easier if you learn how to use an [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)) for the table name.  It's as simple as using `SomeTableNameThatsWayTooLong as long_table` in your query, such as:

```
SELECT LT.Id FROM SomeTableNameThatsWayTooLong AS LT
```

Comment: So in that case, I shouldn't use field names like "student_ID", "teach_ID", "student_name", "teacher_name", but just "id" and "name" in both tables. Right?

Comment: In what database would a column called "student_id" lead to invalid SQL?

Comment: I didn't say it would lead to invalid SQL.  I said that simply using 'id' or 'name' is always valid as long as you qualify that with the table name.  Naming every column student_id, student_name, student_dorm, student_major, etc is going to drive your devs crazy and is unnecessary.

Comment: It really is a matter of preference @martin, but I can tell you that I've seen probably 25+ databases in professional environments, and I think only once have I seen table names prefixed to every column.  Like I mentioned before, the only exception to this is the id column but that is just for readability in joins.  I've personally never found it difficult to read student.id or professor.id though.

Comment: +1.  I go with the rule of qualifying **all** column references in a query. (My personal preference is to use a short table alias, rather than the full table name.) I also prefer to have the column name `id` when it's a unique key in the table.  The column name `student_id` would be used for the name of a foreign key column in another table, which references the `id` column in the `student` table.

Comment: FWIW your first link acknowledges that using the tablename as a prefix (e.g. "student_id") is also a popular naming convention. They don't see a problem with it as long as the schema designer is consistent and doesn't abbreviate the tablename.

Answer (score 2):

I would use aliases rather than table names.

You can assign an [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28SQL%29) to a table in a query, one that is shorter than the table name. That makes the query a lot more readable. Example:

```
SELECT 
    t.name AS teacher_name,
    s.name AS student_name 
FROM 
    teacher AS t 
    INNER JOIN student AS s ON 
        s.id=t.s_id;
```

You can of course use the table name if you don't use aliases, and that would be preferred over your option 2.

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer the foreign key column be named following the pattern **`referenced_table_id`.**   For example, `student_id`, rather than `s_id`. Aside from that, this is the pattern I follow.

Comment: Good call on mentioning alias'.  Our DBA's use crazy long names and typing out StudentClassListDetails before each column gets tedious.  The syntax depends on the database type, but I think most of them are as simple as 'StudentClassListDetails as scld'

Comment: @spencer7593 Good point, having clear names is important to avoid confusion in big databases with a lot of tables that are related.

Comment: ... and having `id` column in every entity table, consistently, as the primary or a unique key is a benefit for developers... it allows for coding "by convention", not making that column name an "exception" that has to have special code. When that pattern isn't there, and I'm looking at SQL that says `ON fee.student_id = fo.student_id`... is that a foreign key to primary key join? which table is that primary key in? or is that a foreign key to foreign key shortcut join? or, is the SQL just wrong? I find having `id` column as PK makes SQL easier to decipher, and makes wrong SQL "look" wrong.

Answer (score -1):

If it doesn't get too long, I prefer prefixing in the table themselves, e.g. teacher.teacher_id, student.student_name.  That way, you are always sure which name or id your are talking about, even if you for get to prefix the table name.

Comment: In modern code-first applications, Id (as a GUID) is the preferred primary key on every table in your database.  There are generic benefits, readability benefits, and no real-world down sides.  Event this platform's cousins use it:  https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new